# List bold pages first with imakeidx

Tags: indexing, sorting, imakeidx

In my document, if an index is the title of a whole chapter, the index is bold. Otherwise, the index is just normal. If the index is from the appendix of my document, it will be italic.

An example would be the following:

> Newton Mechanics: **7**, 3, 200, *321*
>   Quantum Mechanics: **12**, 18, 400, *322*

Is it possible that the page number after the index are sorted `bold`, `ascending`, and then `italic` so that it looks like the desired output?

MWE of the document:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Stichwortverzeichnis, columns=1]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
    heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
    heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
    headings_flag 1
    symhead_positive ""
    numhead_positive ""
    delim_0 "\\dotfill"
    delim_1 "\\dotfill"
    delim_2 "\\dotfill"
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\section{Newton Mechanics\index{Newton Mechanics|textbf}}    
\newpage
Blablabla\index{Newton Mechanics}

...

\section{appendix}
Newton\index{Newton Mechanics|textit}

...

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Is there a way of doing this with `imakeidx` or  `xindy` and alikes?

Comment: The sorting capabilities of `makeindex` are limited, perhaps it is possible with `xindy`, but from the LaTeX aspect this is not related to `imakeidx` or `makeidx` packages

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What tags do you recommend then? I haven't quite found a more suiting one than sorting...

Comment: I don't recommend other tags. I just noted that the makeindex processor has limited sorting skills, which will come to its end when seeing something like `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}`